# Represent $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^4}$ as a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Represent $f(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^4}$ as a power series

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}x^{2n}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

Second derivative is

$$\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}\right)^{''}=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^4}\cdot x(1+8x-2x^2-8x^3+x^4)$$

This gives
$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^4}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n(2n-1)x^{2n-2}}{x(1+8x-2x^2-8x^3+x^4)}$$

I have a proof in combinatorics which involves this series.
How to represent this series using binomial coefficients?

Comment: I am not sure about your method (It seems correct but I don't think you will get a formula), have you tried to develop $(1-x^2)^4$ directly ? you get : $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-4x^2+6x^4-4x^6+x^8}=\sum x^{2n}(4-6x^2+4x^4-x^6)^n$ you could use multinomial coefficients to develop the $n$-power... At the end you will get a formula (complicated but this is a formula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it could be easier expand $(1-x^2)^{-4}$ using the binomial series.

$\begin{align}
(1-x^2)^{-4} &= 1+4x^2 + \frac{(-4)(-4-1)}{2}(-x^2)^2+\frac{(-4)(-4-1)(-4-2)}{3!}(-x^2)^3+ \dots\\
&=1+4x^2+10x^4+20x^6+35x^8+\dots\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{n+2}{3}x^{2n-2}\\
\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^n$$
$$\frac{d^3}{dx^3}(\frac{1}{1-x})=\frac{6}{(1-x)^4}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}$$
$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^4}=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }n(n-1)(n-2)x^{n-3}$$
now replace $x$ by $x^2$
$$\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^4}=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{n=3}^{\infty }n(n-1)(n-2)x^{2n-6}=1+4x^2+10x^4+20x^6+35x^8+..$$